# Getting ids of categories

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get children of categories. But i can't get categories ids.

```
public function profile()
{
    $categories = CourseCategory::where('parent_id', null)->get();
    $children = CourseCategory::where('parent_id', $categories->id)->get();
    return view('user-profile/index')
        ->with('categories', $categories)
        ->with('children', $children);
}
```

how can i get categories ids?

Comment: you have to run a foreach on the $categories as it is a collection

Comment: How can i do that can u give me an example ?

Comment: I think Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#running-database-queries) about db queries has examples that should help you

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use a `whereIn` query, see documentation here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses

Your code could then look something like this...

```
public function profile()
{
    $categories = CourseCategory::where('parent_id', null)->get();
    $category_ids = CourseCategory::where('parent_id', null)->get()->pluck("id")->toArray();

    $children = CourseCategory::whereIn('parent_id', $category_ids)->get();

    return view('user-profile.index')
        ->with(compact('categories', 'children'));
}
```

Although your provided code suggests the above might be sufficient, in reality you would create a `one-to-many relationship`
Read this article
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/one-to-many-relationship-with-a-same-model

Comment: Big thanks for help it's worked : )